# change another form text on closing event

Tags: c#

I would like to change a label's text in my MdiParent Form when a Child Form closes. but I get this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in yourprogram.exe".
This is my code:

```
        private void Employees_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        (MdiParent as MainForm).setStatusText = "Ready";
    }
```

I have this code in my MdiParent Form:

```
public string setStatusText
    {
        set
        {
            tsStatus.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

I tried it on Employees_FormClosed Event as well but I still get the same error. 
I just couldn't see why it's giving me a null reference when I instantiated the class.

Comment: Either `MdiParent` is null, or it isn't castable to type `MainForm`. Can you post the code where you set MdiParent?

Comment: try `((MdiParent as Form) as MainForm)`  but like Baldrik said make sure you set it

Comment: Why not have an event on the child form that the parent subscribes to?

Comment: This is in my MainForm to call the Child Form:                                 private void addEmployeeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employees emp = new Employees();
            emp.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            emp.Show();

            tsStatus.Text = "Adding Employee";
        }

Comment: In my other form, login form, I am able to change the text of a label in the main form using (MdiParent as MainForm).setStatusText = "Ready"; How come with this other child form, it is giving me an error?

Comment: Self-inflicted pain.  Allow the CLR to give you a better diagnostic, do not use *as*.  Use `((MainForm)MdiParent).setStatusText = "Ready";` instead.

Comment: I got it. In my code, emp.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; I should change it to - emp.MdiParent = this only. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is taken form your comment:

```
private void addEmployeeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employees emp = new Employees();
    emp.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    emp.Show();
    tsStatus.Text = "Adding Employee";
}
```

When i understand it right, your `setStatusText` method is within the same class as the `addEmployeeToolStripMenuItem_Click` method.
This means the line `emp.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;` is wrong.
It should be `emp.MdiParent = this;`, because you don't want to set your parent to your child, you want to set yourself as the parent of your child.

**EDIT:**

When you get an `NullReferenceException` when using `as` can mean two things.
Either your variable, in this case `MdiParent`, is `null` or your variable is not of the right type, in this case `MainForm`.

Comment: I commented at the top first before I was able to see your answer thus I wasn't able to see that what I found out by myself is what you have suggested too. Thanks.